# Gantt Chart With reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, gantt-chart

I'm working on an MVC .net web application and I want to design a [Gantt Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) using reporting services. What kind of chart should I choose for designing the report? Can anyone help me to do that? Thank you.

Comment: The question is what chart type should be used to create a Gantt chart style report in Reporting Services. This has nothing to do with "recommendations"  or off-site resources and is a valid problem when building reports using SSRS that falls within the scope of SO. I am voting to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting Services doesn't include Gantt charts as a feature, however it is possible to simulate them using a *range chart* with horizontal bars. The start and end dates of the projects or tasks are used to control the positioning of the horizontal bars on the chart, so that the representation looks similar to a Gantt chart.

Here is an detailed example: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3521/sql-server-reporting-services-range-charts/

Comment: Assuming the downvotes were for the now-defunct link, so I have replaced with a more recent example.